# Can we save few of list items in a separate database?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, sql-server

I have a different requirement that For suppose myCustomList having 40 columns and every 10 columns are similar kind of data. So, I want to save those each group of 10 columns into a specific table[my case 4x10 = 4 tables] in the database(or in content database if possible).

Generally list data will save in AllLists table under WSS_Content database. 
Straight points:

1. can we save few of total columns into specific table (some other db) in out side wss_content db? [like external content db through BCS]
2. Is possible to create tables in wss_content db and save the above columns data there?

Can anybody suggest me to how do I accomplish my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Content Databases as the name suggests is used to store various contents. We can assign different Content Databases for following entities

1. Web Application - In this case all content for that application gets stored here
2. Site Collection - In this case site collection specific content gets stored here

You are confused with database vs. list.

DataBase is the place where the entire content get stored
List can be treated as a table inside the database

Now to resolve you requirement. You can do following

1. Create List which has common fields (You said 10 fields are common)
2. Now in the master list create a lookup field to the common list

Comment: That's great to hear your answer. Still I couldn't get answer .. I have some knowledge how to add External Content database by using BCS But how can I create my own tables (different columns to different tables) and associate to sharepoint list?  Thank you Amal.

Comment: yes.. Lookups is good but my requirement is different so Any other alternative suggestions to create specific table for specific columns..? Thanks Amal

Comment: You store the data common data in SQL table. Create ECT and External List. Then add it as a lookup to your SharePoint list.